# Does new AWS HealthCheck understand when Java application is deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

Background:My Java 7 Elastic Beanstalk application was working fine. It usually uses just one instance but if CPU load reaches 70% it fires up another one, shutting it down if go below 20%, maximum no of instances allowed is two. There can be quite a range of usage so it make financial sense to start with one and just go up to two when needed. The only problem was that at deployment it has to download a 5GB index file from S3 and unzip it, this means total deployment time is thirty minutes.
But I think AWS is aware the application is still deploying and does not start sending requests to it until properly deployed, I have the following ebextension configured

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1800
```

Recently Ive deployed a new version of application and I notice AWS has a new Health Check monitoring that monitors HttpCodes. I think it is returning errors when a new instance of application is still in deployment and causing

**Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively.**

so my server fails, but Im not sure, could HealthCheck be causing the problem, how do I check this ?

Currently workaround is to deploy to faster instance but this means Im now paying for capacity I dont need so is not a financially viable solution longer term.

Answer (score 0):

The new AWS Elastic Beanstalk health check formally called the "enhanced" health check gathers data from various sources and provides you a health status and color along with causes for the assigned health for the environment and all the instances. The sources include data from EC2 instances, ELB health check, cloudwatch metrics for ELB, SQS etc.

If you are seeing "Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively." in the causes then it means that the instance is failing the load balancer health check. Possible reasons for this message coming from ELB are documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html). To clarify ELB will not send traffic to your instance if the load balancer health check is failing. This is the behavior of the load balancer whether or not you are using the enhanced health reporting system. Enhanced health just surfaces this information from ELB into the beanstalk health causes/events.
If you have one instance in your environment and it takes 30 minutes to do a deployment it is possible that during the deployment, your environment will not be serving any traffic.

Can you provide the health check configuration for your load balancer? You can find the health check in the load balancing panel of the beanstalk configuration page as shown [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html).

If you have a reliable health check URL in your application, to notify the ELB that your instance is ready to serve traffic, then you should use that for your health check instead of the default TCP:80 check.
You can also see whether your instances are receiving traffic during deployment or not by looking at the Health pane on the AWS Management console.

But to reiterate, if you have only one instance and deployment takes a long time then during that period your environment will be unavailable for customer traffic. That may be ok for some usecases. If not then it is recommended that you use at least 2 instances and rolling deployments (health or time based) with batch size < number of instances.

Even if you have a faster instance that takes say 5 minutes to download the large file from S3 and process it, then for those 5 minutes your instance will not be able to serve customer traffic if the health check for your load balancer is not passing.

Is downloading the 5 GB file a prerequisite for running your application? Is it necessary for you to download this file as part of your application deployment or could you also do this as part of a background thread in your application? If it is not critical to download the file during the update you can have very fast deployments and your instance will be ready to serve traffic instantly.

The message "Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively." is just telling you that the ELB thinks your instance is unhealthy (based on your health check configuration) and hence is not receiving any traffic.

When you say "so my server fails", do you mean that the health of the environment is something like Severe/Red? If that is the case then yes with a single instance behind your load balancer and the deployment taking over 30 minutes, it is expected that the instance will not be healthy as per load balancer during the deployment. Again if you think your instance can serve traffic even before the deployment is complete (the long poll being the download from S3), then you should consider moving the download from S3 to a background thread, so that your application is unhealthy for a shorter duration and downtime is minimized.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: the 5GB file is a lucene search index that is searched until this has been downloaded and unpacked the application cannot do anything useful - I cant chnage this. This is not a problem for the initial deployment as I use the blue/green mechanism so I dont make the new deployment live until it is properly deployed, until that point user are accessing the currrent deployment. My problem is purely that whilst cpu usage is usually only about 20% it can increase to 60% triggering an additional instance it seems this isnt working properly now returning errors before deployment finished.

Comment: You can suspend auto scaling processes on your environment during a deployment. Check autoscaling guide for the same.